# Jetty + OSGi results in strange cache errors

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to run an embedded jetty instance from an OSGi server.

When the server starts I can see the following in the log:

```
Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1f437060{/browser,bundle://201.0:24/browser,AVAILABLE}
```

The first request is successful but later requests will result in a stack trace, e.g.

```
WARN | ResourceCache | Could not load bundle://201.0:24/browser/index.html true 1415275444922 java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9] java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=29 cap=29]
WARN | ResourceCache |
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \browser\index.html (Det går inte att hitta sökvägen)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)[:1.8.0_20]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)[:1.8.0_20]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.readFrom(BufferUtil.java:408)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache.getIndirectBuffer(ResourceCache.java:296)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache$Content.getIndirectBuffer(ResourceCache.java:478)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache$Content.getInputStream(ResourceCache.java:525)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:427)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:345)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:887)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:493)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:582)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:261)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:101)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:546)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)[201:com.test.mybundle:1.0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_20]
```

My guess is that the path prefix `bundle://` is not supported. Could this be the problem, and if so, how could this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceMix already has a build in Web Feature. You just need install the war or http feature which will also install a Jetty Server. That's all you need to do, no extras to install in a ServiceMix/Karaf Container.

Comment: The reason I try to deploy an embedded Jetty server is because it comes from a third party, and I would prefer minimal change to the code.